How do i use request(query_params) in pydanctic TestSchemaOut @root_validator?
I want to use the requested parameter in the root_validator below, but there is no way.
Please tell me how to use query params in Pydantic.
class TestSchemaOut(Schema):
    """
        OUT TEST
    """

    test_no: int
    test_exposure_yn: str
    test_modified_ip: str
    test_modified_datetime: datetime
    test_modified_user_no: int
    test_created_ip: str
    test_created_datetime: datetime
    test_created_user_no: int
    test_created_user: Optional[dict] = None

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def check_created_user(cls, values):
        print("test")


        return values

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

There doesn't seem to be an option to access the request in validator and root_validator.

Could you please clarify what parameter you'd like to validate? One of specified in your schema (test_no, test_exposure_yn  etc.)? Or could you provide more code to better understand the context?
